# accessing atomicly two scalar fields

Tags: c, pthreads, atomic, c11

In a multi-threaded (Linux/amd64, Pthreads, C11) application I have a `struct` (`momitem_st` in [monimelt.h](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/monimelt.h)) containing notably two fields

```
uint16_t i_paylkind;
void* i_payload;
```

(if needed, I could change the type of `i_paylkind`  to some other integral type, e.g. `uintptr_t`  or `atomic_uint`)

FWIW, `i_paylkind`  is a discriminant defining the actual `struct`  runtime-type the `i_payload` is pointing to.

Is it possible to access these two fields atomically (w.r.t. other threads accessing the same `struct`). Of course I also have a `pthread_mutex_t i_mtx;` in the same structure which I could lock (using `pthread_mutex_lock`). But for performance reasons I might want to avoid that (perhaps [transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory) might be relevant)

It looks like [`<stdtomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) does not provide any machinery for that.

(question related to my [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/) GPLv3+ software)

Comment: I believe you either need hardware support for double-compare-and-swap operations, or introduce a higher-level lock (spinlock, mutex, up to you).

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, no not at all. Atomic types are defined for all types but for arrays.

Comment: As an aside: pthread_mutex_t is usually a typedef for an integral type. That should not impose huge performance penalties by default.

Comment: @Jens You'll still have a higher-level (spin)lock under the hood.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, yes and no, you have whatever your compiler provider found suitable. If e.g your struct has a size that is suitable for a  lowlevel atomic operation, your compiler can implement it as such. Modern processors often have 128 bit atomic instructions for a whole cache line. But this is not for you as an application programmer to know. The language covers this. (BTW, gcc doesn't implement this with a spinlock but with a mutex)

Comment: @Jens So we agree that current compilers implement this as a higher-level lock. In the case of gcc, this doesn't solve OP's problem since he explicitly wants to avoid mutices.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, he wants it if it is possible, and the compiler constructor knows that, and then he will do that. But maybe you let Basile decide himself, what is an answer for him.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, no we don't agree on that. If the architecture has an instruction for that, the compiler implementor will chose that instruction. For gcc this depends on the architecture option that you provide. `-march=native` is a good idea.

Comment: @Jens And how is that different from my very first comment?

Answer (score 4):

If you have really a C11 compiler, the `_Atomic` qualifier applies to any data type. Just use it. For `struct` types, the only things that you can do is load and store, unfortunately, you don't have access to the individual members.

Comment: And maybe add a pre-processor check `#ifdef __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__ #error No atomic  #endif`? I don't think the _Atomic qualifier is mandatory to implement.

Comment: @Lundin, the question text is formulated under the assumption that `stdatomic.h` exists. In C11, either you have all atomics, including `_Atomic`, or nothing.